# Django H14 Heroku error, how do i fix this?

Tags: django, heroku

2020-09-08T17:05:06.205027+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/" host=uvdocdash.herokuapp.com request_id=f17ceaee-3e7c-4eba-aebf-19dd4b424eee fwd="70.39.71.29" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https

I get this error in the logs, so far I havent been able to find out why my app isnt working. It's a django app, and the requirments.txt is correct as far as i know.

```
asgiref==3.2.10
Django==3.1.1
gunicorn==20.0.4
pytz==2020.1
sqlparse==0.3.1
django-heroku >= 0.3.1
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a Procfile to your folder that has manage.py in it. Just add a file called Procfile and add web: gunicorn projectname.wsgi inside of that file. save and push.